# Java Operator Precedence Complex (postfix,unary,relational,logical AND,assignment)

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence

The below code complies to output `b1=false`.

```
int x=1;
boolean b1 = ++x >= 1 && x++ == 1;
System.out.println("b1="+b1);
```

But according to the [Java Operator Precedence Table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) it must output **`b1=true`**.

**Can any one please explain me step by step what happens?**

The order of operators used for this question according to the [Java Operator Precedence Table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) are,

1> postfix - `x++`

2> unary - `++x`

3> relational - `>=`

4> equality - `==`

5> logical AND - `&&`

***The method I used,***

1> `++x >= 1 && x++ == 1`

2> `++x >= 1 && 1   == 1` now `x=2`

3> `3   >= 1 && 1   == 1` now `x=3`

4> `true     && 1   == 1`

5> `true     && true`

6> `true`

So therefore it should output `b1=true`

**Where have I gone wrong?**

What I'm asking is simple, We consider operator precedence **over** evaluation order for the expression, `int x=1+2*3;` **BUT** why use evaluation order **over** operator precedence for `++x >= 1 && x++ == 1;` **???**

Comment: *Operator precedence* and *order of evaluation* are two different things. The left side of `&&` is evaluated first. (In general, the left side of things is evaluated first.)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't confuse operator precedence and evaluation order. Expressions are evaluated from left to right, regardless of operator precedence.

**Step 1**: Operator precedence is applied to your expression by grouping sub-expressions:

```
boolean b1 = ++x >= 1 && x++ == 1;
//becomes
boolean b1 = ( ((++x) >= 1) && ((x++) == 1) );
```

**Step 2**: evaluation of the sub-expressions is then done from left to right, regardless of operator precedence: `++x` is therefore evaluated before `x++`.

Note however that `x++` is only evaluated if the left part of the condition is true, otherwise the `&&` returns false without evaluating the second condition.

In other words, your code is equivalent to:

```
int x = 1;
int temp1 = ++x; //temp1 = 2
boolean b1 = false;
if (temp1 >= 1) {
  int temp2 = x++; //temp2 = 2
  if (temp2 == 1) {
    b1 = true;
  }
}
```

**Reference**: you can read more about expression evaluation in [JLS #15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7).

Comment: That code wasn't the equivalent - that was for `&`, not `&&`. Edited; feel free to roll back.

Comment: Indeed good point thanks.

Comment: Okay thanks, but could you tell me another example where expressions are evaluated from left to right and then operator precedence applied?
(without using logical operators)

Comment: Say: `x = 1; y = x++ + ++x;` - in that case y will be 1 + 3 = 4.

Comment: anyway x++ (postfix) has an higher precedence than ++x (unary operator or prefix)

Comment: @Otty he fact that x++ has precedence over ++x is probably irrelevant because I don't think you can build an expression that has both prefix and postfix operators applied to the same variable (`++x++` is illegal - but if it were not I suppose it would be evaluated as `++(x++)`)...

Comment: @assylias, I don't get the answer for my question on your marked as dulicate question, :3
What I'm asking is simple,
We consider operator precedence over evaluation order for the expression, `int x=1+2*3;` **BUT** why use evaluation order over operator precedence for `++x >= 1 && x++ == 1;` **???**

Comment: @Otty I think the accepted answer on the duplicate contains information to answer your question. In any case I have edited my answer to make it clearer - let me know if it makes more sense now.